# Is it safe to connect Neon indicating lamps with resistors to defrost timer and other fridge components?

Tags: resistors, ac, safety, indicator, thermostat

I want to connect some indicative <strike>LEDs</strike> neon lights pulled from the switches of a multiple ways extension cord to the fridge. Initially the defrost timer, then later all parts and wires individually so I can tell what's going on with a glance at any given time. Is it safe to connect each of the three timer terminals back to its neutral on the fourth neutral terminal with those <strike>LEDs</strike>Neon lamps?
A negligent refrigerator technician destroyed the enclosing box that contained the timer, capacitor and and a wall dc adapter and he soldered there leaving spaghetti of wires without the cover and every time the floor is cleaned something goes wrong. I replaced the timer and the adapter and added better terminals, joints and a socket enclosed everything except the adapter socket in a transparent sealed food container instead of the old box and was thinking of adding the <strike>LEDs</strike> neon lamps to monitor it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That't not even a LED in the picture. And safety depends how are you going to connect it and where exactly, draw a schematic.

Comment: @Justme Yes just noticed, my bad. Does it make any difference since leds work in a similar setup?

Comment: A neon lamp needs around 80V and emits light by ionising neon gas. An LED needs something like 1.5V to 5V and emits light from a p-n semiconductor junction. They couldn't be much more different.

Comment: LEDs also can withstand only about 5V voltage over it in the reverse direction. So it can damage immediately or degrade very quickly and stop working when connected to 120VAC via a resistor. Indeed, very different from neon lamps.

Answer (score 3):

If you connect a neon + resistor between something and neutral, it will light up whenever the voltage is more than about 80V, and will go out of the voltage is much less than 80V.  If that's what you need, then you can do it.

Make sure you insulate those wires properly to avoid making things even worse than they are.

A neon takes only a very small current when operating, and shouldn't mess up the fridge controls.

Comment: I fixed it by over-insulating and changing the adaptor and timer which went bad after splashes from cleaning I used ready connectors beneath layers of shrinking tubes, electrical tapes and superglue in between where water is expected (super glue is flammable when it's whet and dangrous with shrink tube and a lighter) . I also added vents and drain holes in the new box and will also add a plastic grill beneath the components because there are at least three water sources where the box is installed, I will try to get the original box or a new fridge after the curfew. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting a neon indicator and series resistor across the defrost heater is a valid thing to do; the neon will illuminate when the resistor is energised.  Provided that this is done in accordance with the appropriate electrical safety practices it is quite safe.  A thought experiment I once heard was ‘can I open the box and lick everything I can see’.  Depending where you live there may be laws restricting who can carry out such work.

Comment: What about the other two pins:the motor and the timer I self. We have public holiday, curfew and total lockdown all simultaneously for the next two weeks with stranded guests and bringing a technician home is not allowed and take the fridges away is not an option. I've been electrocuted by main ac too many times in my life but I have never been electrocuted  since I started messing with it.

Comment: Placing an indicator between the M and C terminals of the motor appears to be ok, that will illuminate when the motor is running (is that what you want?).  I’m not sure about the timer - under what conditions do you want the neon to illuminate?

Comment: When the compressor(motor) is not working in normal condition its either the defrost cycle from the timer or the thermostat is satisfied. Or if there is a problem most probably the timer  stucks or the DC fan is not working casing the freezer where the thermostat lives to be very cold and the food compartment very warm.

Comment: Basically If the motor is not running, I want to know why, the DC part will require LED but I don't know how (in parallel? ) and when you said across do you mean parallel?

Comment: I see that the fan motor runs from DC, but there’s no indication of the voltage.  You’re right that neons are best suited to AC and LEDs to DC.  Like neons, LEDs need a series resistor to limit current.  And yes, when I say ‘across’ I mean ‘in parallel’.